# Did not unplug computer, power outage. Is it safe?

Tags: power-supply, power, surge-protection

My office building is doing some maintenance work and they said they will shut off the power supply from midnight to 6am -- They told everyone in the building to turn off their computers and unplug them.

I shut down my desktop computer and turned off the monitor, ***but I forgot to unplug the power switches and switch it off. So my power plug switch is still on.***

What are the chances when I go in on Monday that the computer will be spoilt? Because I turned it off, so will it reduce the chances? If I did leave it on, does it increase the chances of it spoiling? Or does it make no difference?

Also, is there a higher chance of my computer getting damaged from power outages or lightning strikes? All other things being equal.

Comment: Since you did turn it off, I doubt there will be any damage. The reason they want you to unplug the computers is to protect the people working on the electrical system.

Answer (score 0):

> What are the chances when I go in on Monday that the computer will be
>   spoilt?

At worst the system's power might broken, however, it's fifty-fifty. it depends the maintenance work.

> Because I turned it off, so will it reduce the chances? If I did leave
>   it on, does it increase the chances of it spoiling? Or does it make no
>   difference?

Yes, if you didn't turn off your system then your system's OS might damage and other hardware will might broken.

Comment: Thanks, so there is a 50% chance nothing will happen? I dont understand -- my computer is off, so how exactly would my computer be spoilt even if my plug is switched on?

Also, meaning I switched off the computer so it is using less power/electricity than if it is turned on? So in turn that reduces the chances of the computer being spoilt?

Comment: Yes, it's correct. your computer is off, however, your system power is on and the 3.3 volt power is on your main board. if the power swing occurred then it might damage your system power.